# How to use data from $http in other controller

Tags: angularjs

How can I use the totalResults outside of the function that Im setting it? I just cant wrap my head around how to do it, I need to use the totalResults that I gather from my database and use in another function to calculate the amount of pages. I do this so I dont load all the data to the client but I still need to know the total count of rows in the database table.

**My json looks like:**

```
Object {total: 778, animals: Array[20]}
```

**Angular:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AnimalController', ['$scope', 'animalSrc', function($scope, animalSrc)
{
    $scope.animals = [];

    var skip = 0;
    var take = 20;
    var totalResults = null;
    //$scope.totalResults = null;

    $scope.list = function()
    {
        animalSrc.getAll(skip, take, function(data) {
            $scope.animals = $scope.animals.concat(data.animals);

            // I need to be able to use this outside of function ($scope.list)
            totalResults = data.total;
            //$scope.totalResults = data.total;
        });
    };

    $scope.showMore = function()
    {
        skip += 20;
        $scope.list();
    };

    $scope.hasMore = function()
    {
        //
    };

    // Outputs null, should be the total rows from the $http request
    console.log(totalResults); 
}]);

app.factory('animalSrc', ['$http', function($http)
{
    // Private //

    return {
        getAll: function(skip, take, callback)
        {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'url' + skip + '/' + take
            }).
            success(function(data) {
                callback(data);
            }).
            error(function(data) {
                console.log('error: ' + data);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Your code should be working, console.log invocation will always print null because it is called before totalData variable is set

Comment: It does work but how can I get the console.log at the bottom of the controller to be updated with my total from the $http request so I can use it?

Comment: console.log at the bottom will never output total count as long as you are sending request inside the controller. If you want to update page count, you should do this in callback. If you want to do this in another function you should call this function from callback

Comment: Oh now I understand, you have a second controller somewhere responsible for paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start thinking asynchronously. Your console.log is called before the $http has returned and totalResults has been set. Therefore, totalResults will always be null.

You need to find some way to delay the call to console.log so that the $http call can finish before you run console.log. One way to do this would be to put the console.log call inside your callback function so that it is definitely called after $http's success.

A more elegant way to do this is to use promises. angular.js implements $q, which is similar to Q, a promise library.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Instead of creating a callback function in getAll, you return a promise. Inside $http success, you resolve the promise with the data. Then, in your controller, you have a function that is called when the promise is resolved. Promises are nice because they can be passed around and they allow you to control the flow of your asynchronous code without blocking.

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that, but from my understanding I thought $http was already returning a promise?

Comment: $http is based on the promise library, but I find it much more elegant to have a $q.defer() object -- that way you can separate what you do inside your service and in your controller. You have sort of implemented the same functionality of a promise by adding a callback to your function which is why adding the console.log to the end of the callback will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a boilerplate I was just working on for myself for similar setup where data is an object that needs to be split into more than one scope item. Issue you weren't grasping is storing the data within the service, not just using service to retrieve data. Then the data items are available across multple controllers and directives by injecting service

```
app.run(function(MyDataService){
  MyDataService.init();
})

app.factory('MyDataService',function($http,$q){

  var myData = {
    deferreds:{},

    mainDataSchema:['count','items'],
    init:function(){
      angular.forEach(myData.mainDataSchema,function(val,idx){ 
        /* create deferreds and promises*/
        myData.deferreds[val]=$q.defer();
        myData[val]= myData.deferreds[val].promise
      });     
      /* load the data*/
      myData.loadData();

    },     

    loadData:function(){
         $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
           /* create resolves for promises*/
           angular.forEach(myData.mainDataSchema,function(val,idx){            
             myData.deferreds[val].resolve(response[val]);
        });
       /* TODO -create rejects*/

      })

    }
  }

  return myData;

  })

app.controller('Ctrl_1', function($scope,MyDataService ) {
    $scope.count = MyDataService.count;
    $scope.items =MyDataService.items;
});

app.controller('Ctrl_2', function($scope,MyDataService ) {
  $scope.items =MyDataService.items;
  $scope.count = MyDataService.count;
});
```

[Plunker demo](http://plunker.co/edit/hHJhs92hRkBjTwUYygRo?p=preview)